# C++ wont prompt follow up statements

Tags: c++, cin, cout

Everytime I run this code, Only the very first cout and cin statement will allow for user input. It wont follow up with the other lines of code. Just prints to the terminal

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int adultTickets, childTickets, grossProfit, netProfit, distributor, adultSold, childSold;
    char movieName, movieTitle;
    cout << "Please enter the name of the movie: ";
    cin >> movieName;
    cout << "\nHow many ADULT tickets sold: ";
    cin >> adultSold;
    cout << "\nHow many CHILD tickets sold: ";
    cin >> childSold;
    
    adultTickets = 6 * adultSold;
    childTickets = 3 * childSold;
    grossProfit = adultTickets + childTickets;
    netProfit = (grossProfit * 20) / 100;
    distributor = grossProfit - netProfit;
    
    cout << "\nAdult Tickets Sold: " << adultSold << endl;
    cout << "Child Tickets Sold: " << childSold << endl;
    cout << "Gross Box Office Profit: " << grossProfit << endl;
    cout << "Amount paid to distributor: " << distributor << endl;
    cout << "Net Box Ofiice Profit: " << netProfit << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your `movieName` and `movieTitle` are declared as being a *single* `char` each. That's probably not what you want — try using `std::string` for those instead.

Comment: Indeed, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just figured it out by declaring the string size to my `movieName[25]` variable.